# Access exe/jar of remote machine from javascript

Tags: javascript

I got an task to access an exe or (a file located on particular location like C drive) from browser. There would be a button on webpage and an exe on local machine of user. when i click on that button, it invoke that exe and pass parameter to it. Is it possible to do it through javascript? Please suggest other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Security restrictions in browsers prevent you from either:

- Launching executables on the client computer
- Accessing files on the client computer

… so you can't, for two different security reasons.